# which order scipy.misc.imread reads the color images?

Tags: python, image, scipy

I am using python and for reading the image I am using the following method

```
scipy.misc.imread
```

I am wondering what is the order of color with respect to axis, is it `RGB or BGR` or any other order?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is RGB but just to prove it (you can do it yourself easily), first I create an image using a paint tool such as photoshop of solid color (R=75, G=125, B=255):

[image]

Now check it with the following snippet:

```
>>> from scipy.misc import imread
>>> img = imread("foo.jpg")
>>> img[0,0,:]
 [ 75 125 255]
```